# Undefined x values in chart.js

Tags: json, datatables, chart.js

This is my data retrieved from a staff.php file

[staff.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsR1n.png)

I would like to try to a Chart from this data with first_name + last_name on the x axis, and age on the y axis. However all I get on the x axis is a lot of "Player undefined" values instead of the names. The y axis is not correct either. What am I doing wrong egen regering till the values in the php?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "staff.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var players = [];
            var ages = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                players.push("Player " + data[i].first_name);
                ages.push(data[i].age);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: players,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Player Score',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: ages
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is console.log(data)

```
{"data":[{"DT_RowId":"row_1","first_name":"Tiger","last_name":"Nixon","position":"System Architect","email":"t.nixon@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421","age":"61","salary":"320800","start_date":"2011-04-25"},{"DT_RowId":"row_2","first_name":"Garrett","last_name":"Winters","position":"Accountant","email":"g.winters@datatables.net","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422","age":"63","salary":"170750","start_date":"2011-07-25"},{"DT_RowId":"row_3","first_name":"Ashton","last_name":"Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","email":"a.cox@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562","age":"66","salary":"86000","start_date":"2009-01-12"},{"DT_RowId":"row_4","first_name":"Cedric","last_name":"Kelly","position":"Senior Javascript Developer","email":"c.kelly@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"6224","age":"22","salary":"433060","start_date":"2012-03-29"},{"DT_RowId":"row_5","first_name":"Airi","last_name":"Satou","position":"Accountant","email":"a.satou@datatables.net","office":"Tokyo","extn":"5407","age":"33","salary":"162700","start_date":"2008-11-28"},{"DT_RowId":"row_6","first_name":"Brielle","last_name":"Williamson","position":"Integration Specialist","email":"b.williamson@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"4804","age":"61","salary":"372000","start_date":"2012-12-02"},{"DT_RowId":"row_7","first_name":"Herrod","last_name":"Chandler","position":"Sales Assistant","email":"h.chandler@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"9608","age":"59","salary":"137500","start_date":"2012-08-06"},{"DT_RowId":"row_8","first_name":"Rhona","last_name":"Davidson","position":"Integration Specialist","email":"r.davidson@datatables.net","office":"Tokyo","extn":"6200","age":"55","salary":"327900","start_date":"2010-10-14"},{"DT_RowId":"row_9","first_name":"Colleen","last_name":"Hurst","position":"Javascript Developer","email":"c.hurst@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"2360","age":"39","salary":"205500","start_date":"2009-09-15"},{"DT_RowId":"row_10","first_name":"Sonya","last_name":"Frost","position":"Software Engineer","email":"s.frost@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"1667","age":"23","salary":"103600","start_date":"2008-12-13"},{"DT_RowId":"row_11","first_name":"Jena","last_name":"Gaines","position":"Office Manager","email":"j.gaines@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"3814","age":"30","salary":"90560","start_date":"2008-12-19"},{"DT_RowId":"row_12","first_name":"Quinn","last_name":"Flynn","position":"Support Lead","email":"q.flynn@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"9497","age":"22","salary":"342000","start_date":"2013-03-03"},{"DT_RowId":"row_13","first_name":"Charde","last_name":"Marshall","position":"Regional Director","email":"c.marshall@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"6741","age":"36","salary":"470600","start_date":"2008-10-16"},{"DT_RowId":"row_14","first_name":"Haley","last_name":"Kennedy","position":"Senior Marketing Designer","email":"h.kennedy@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"3597","age":"43","salary":"313500","start_date":"2012-12-18"},{"DT_RowId":"row_15","first_name":"Tatyana","last_name":"Fitzpatrick","position":"Regional Director","email":"t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"1965","age":"19","salary":"385750","start_date":"2010-03-17"},{"DT_RowId":"row_16","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Silva","position":"Marketing Designer","email":"m.silva@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"1581","age":"66","salary":"198500","start_date":"2012-11-27"},{"DT_RowId":"row_17","first_name":"Paul","last_name":"Byrd","position":"Chief Financial Officer (CFO)","email":"p.byrd@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"3059","age":"64","salary":"725000","start_date":"2010-06-09"},{"DT_RowId":"row_18","first_name":"Gloria","last_name":"Little","position":"Systems Administrator","email":"g.little@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"1721","age":"59","salary":"237500","start_date":"2009-04-10"},{"DT_RowId":"row_19","first_name":"Bradley","last_name":"Greer","position":"Software Engineer","email":"b.greer@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"2558","age":"41","salary":"132000","start_date":"2012-10-13"},{"DT_RowId":"row_20","first_name":"Dai","last_name":"Rios","position":"Personnel Lead","email":"d.rios@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"2290","age":"35","salary":"217500","start_date":"2012-09-26"},{"DT_RowId":"row_21","first_name":"Jenette","last_name":"Caldwell","position":"Development Lead","email":"j.caldwell@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"1937","age":"30","salary":"345000","start_date":"2011-09-03"},{"DT_RowId":"row_22","first_name":"Yuri","last_name":"Berry","position":"Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)","email":"y.berry@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"6154","age":"40","salary":"675000","start_date":"2009-06-25"},{"DT_RowId":"row_23","first_name":"Caesar","last_name":"Vance","position":"Pre-Sales Support","email":"c.vance@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"8330","age":"21","salary":"106450","start_date":"2011-12-12"},{"DT_RowId":"row_24","first_name":"Doris","last_name":"Wilder","position":"Sales Assistant","email":"d.wilder@datatables.net","office":"Sidney","extn":"3023","age":"23","salary":"85600","start_date":"2010-09-20"},{"DT_RowId":"row_25","first_name":"Angelica","last_name":"Ramos","position":"Chief Executive Officer (CEO)","email":"a.ramos@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"5797","age":"47","salary":"1200000","start_date":"2009-10-09"},{"DT_RowId":"row_26","first_name":"Gavin","last_name":"Joyce","position":"Developer","email":"g.joyce@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"8822","age":"42","salary":"92575","start_date":"2010-12-22"},{"DT_RowId":"row_27","first_name":"Jennifer","last_name":"Chang","position":"Regional Director","email":"j.chang@datatables.net","office":"Singapore","extn":"9239","age":"28","salary":"357650","start_date":"2010-11-14"},{"DT_RowId":"row_28","first_name":"Brenden","last_name":"Wagner","position":"Software Engineer","email":"b.wagner@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1314","age":"28","salary":"206850","start_date":"2011-06-07"},{"DT_RowId":"row_29","first_name":"Fiona","last_name":"Green","position":"Chief Operating Officer (COO)","email":"f.green@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"2947","age":"48","salary":"850000","start_date":"2010-03-11"},{"DT_RowId":"row_30","first_name":"Shou","last_name":"Itou","position":"Regional Marketing","email":"s.itou@datatables.net","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8899","age":"20","salary":"163000","start_date":"2011-08-14"},{"DT_RowId":"row_31","first_name":"Michelle","last_name":"House","position":"Integration Specialist","email":"m.house@datatables.net","office":"Sidney","extn":"2769","age":"37","salary":"95400","start_date":"2011-06-02"},{"DT_RowId":"row_32","first_name":"Suki","last_name":"Burks","position":"Developer","email":"s.burks@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"6832","age":"53","salary":"114500","start_date":"2009-10-22"},{"DT_RowId":"row_33","first_name":"Prescott","last_name":"Bartlett","position":"Technical Author","email":"p.bartlett@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"3606","age":"27","salary":"145000","start_date":"2011-05-07"},{"DT_RowId":"row_34","first_name":"Gavin","last_name":"Cortez","position":"Team Leader","email":"g.cortez@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"2860","age":"22","salary":"235500","start_date":"2008-10-26"},{"DT_RowId":"row_35","first_name":"Martena","last_name":"Mccray","position":"Post-Sales support","email":"m.mccray@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"8240","age":"46","salary":"324050","start_date":"2011-03-09"},{"DT_RowId":"row_36","first_name":"Unity","last_name":"Butler","position":"Marketing Designer","email":"u.butler@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"5384","age":"47","salary":"85675","start_date":"2009-12-09"},{"DT_RowId":"row_37","first_name":"Howard","last_name":"Hatfield","position":"Office Manager","email":"h.hatfield@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"7031","age":"51","salary":"164500","start_date":"2008-12-16"},{"DT_RowId":"row_38","first_name":"Hope","last_name":"Fuentes","position":"Secretary","email":"h.fuentes@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"6318","age":"41","salary":"109850","start_date":"2010-02-12"},{"DT_RowId":"row_39","first_name":"Vivian","last_name":"Harrell","position":"Financial Controller","email":"v.harrell@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"9422","age":"62","salary":"452500","start_date":"2009-02-14"},{"DT_RowId":"row_40","first_name":"Timothy","last_name":"Mooney","position":"Office Manager","email":"t.mooney@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"7580","age":"37","salary":"136200","start_date":"2008-12-11"},{"DT_RowId":"row_41","first_name":"Jackson","last_name":"Bradshaw","position":"Director","email":"j.bradshaw@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"1042","age":"65","salary":"645750","start_date":"2008-09-26"},{"DT_RowId":"row_42","first_name":"Olivia","last_name":"Liang","position":"Support Engineer","email":"o.liang@datatables.net","office":"Singapore","extn":"2120","age":"64","salary":"234500","start_date":"2011-02-03"},{"DT_RowId":"row_43","first_name":"Bruno","last_name":"Nash","position":"Software Engineer","email":"b.nash@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"6222","age":"38","salary":"163500","start_date":"2011-05-03"},{"DT_RowId":"row_44","first_name":"Sakura","last_name":"Yamamoto","position":"Support Engineer","email":"s.yamamoto@datatables.net","office":"Tokyo","extn":"9383","age":"37","salary":"139575","start_date":"2009-08-19"},{"DT_RowId":"row_45","first_name":"Thor","last_name":"Walton","position":"Developer","email":"t.walton@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"8327","age":"61","salary":"98540","start_date":"2013-08-11"},{"DT_RowId":"row_46","first_name":"Finn","last_name":"Camacho","position":"Support Engineer","email":"f.camacho@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"2927","age":"47","salary":"87500","start_date":"2009-07-07"},{"DT_RowId":"row_47","first_name":"Serge","last_name":"Baldwin","position":"Data Coordinator","email":"s.baldwin@datatables.net","office":"Singapore","extn":"8352","age":"64","salary":"138575","start_date":"2012-04-09"},{"DT_RowId":"row_48","first_name":"Zenaida","last_name":"Frank","position":"Software Engineer","email":"z.frank@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"7439","age":"63","salary":"125250","start_date":"2010-01-04"},{"DT_RowId":"row_49","first_name":"Zorita","last_name":"Serrano","position":"Software Engineer","email":"z.serrano@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"4389","age":"56","salary":"115000","start_date":"2012-06-01"},{"DT_RowId":"row_50","first_name":"Jennifer","last_name":"Acosta","position":"Junior Javascript Developer","email":"j.acosta@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"3431","age":"43","salary":"75650","start_date":"2013-02-01"},{"DT_RowId":"row_51","first_name":"Cara","last_name":"Stevens","position":"Sales Assistant","email":"c.stevens@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"3990","age":"46","salary":"145600","start_date":"2011-12-06"},{"DT_RowId":"row_52","first_name":"Hermione","last_name":"Butler","position":"Regional Director","email":"h.butler@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"1016","age":"47","salary":"356250","start_date":"2011-03-21"},{"DT_RowId":"row_53","first_name":"Lael","last_name":"Greer","position":"Systems Administrator","email":"l.greer@datatables.net","office":"London","extn":"6733","age":"21","salary":"103500","start_date":"2009-02-27"},{"DT_RowId":"row_54","first_name":"Jonas","last_name":"Alexander","position":"Developer","email":"j.alexander@datatables.net","office":"San Francisco","extn":"8196","age":"30","salary":"86500","start_date":"2010-07-14"},{"DT_RowId":"row_55","first_name":"Shad","last_name":"Decker","position":"Regional Director","email":"s.decker@datatables.net","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"6373","age":"51","salary":"183000","start_date":"2008-11-13"},{"DT_RowId":"row_56","first_name":"Michael","last_name":"Bruce","position":"Javascript Developer","email":"m.bruce@datatables.net","office":"Singapore","extn":"5384","age":"29","salary":"183000","start_date":"2011-06-27"},{"DT_RowId":"row_57","first_name":"Donna","last_name":"Snider","position":"Customer Support","email":"d.snider@datatables.net","office":"New York","extn":"4226","age":"27","salary":"112000","start_date":"2011-01-25"}],"options":[],"files":[]}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I converted the JSON string into a javascript object using JSON.parse

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "staff.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            data = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);
            var player = [];
            var age = [];

            for(var i=0; i<data.data.length;i++) {
                player.push("Player " + data.data[i].first_name);
                age.push(data.data[i].age);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: player,
                datasets : [
                    {
                        label: 'Player Score',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                        data: age
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata,

            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Please include the output of `console.log(data)` so that we can tell what's wrong

Comment: I included it now in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it can be seen that your data is actually included in `data.data` because `data` variable contains a property with the name of `data`

Also there is another flaw in your code. In javascript we can't iterate items of an array with `for (var i in arr)` (this can only be used to iterate through keys of an object)

So you should change the `for` part of your code to the following

```
var arr = data.data;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            item = arr[i];
            players.push("Player " + item.first_name);
            ages.push(item.age);
        }
```

Indeed it's better to rename the variable named `data` to `response`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "staff.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
})
```

Comment: I did change to data.data but then I received no names on the x axis, compared to "Player undefined" before.

Comment: @jokr1 I updated the answer there was another flaw considering using `for` for an `array`

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, but when I converted it from JSON string to Javascript object it worked! Posted the solution above. Thanks for all your help ehsan!